# Xcode not showing variable/class/type info when mouse hovers, like Visual Studio does. How to activate it?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio

So, I just moved my entire project from Windows/VS (a c++ project) into OSX/Xcode and although I knew it wasn't going to be the same, there is a feature that I am missing very much from Visual Studio....that is, when I hover the mouse over any variable, class, function call, or stl-type in visual studio it gives me the objects full datatype, even when it is an "auto" variable, as seen below.

[image: popup info]

The mouse was hovering over the "letterDescription" auto type and the pop-up info gave its future/inferred type and even the namespace where it belongs 'std::'.

Does Xcode have something like this? Because right now when I hover over anything it doesn't give me jack! I've been playing around with the settings but no luck!

Comment: You normally would either click on the declaration, or option-click to get a popover definition. If you want to see where it inherits from command-click the item.

Comment: If you hover over letterDescription I would expect to see a little 'eye' icon you can click on..

Comment: It is not doing that. I hover the mouse over anything and it pretty much doesn't do crap! I have a theory that it doesn't do it because my project is C++ mainly, but then again it is not doing it with any of the Objective C code either.

Comment: (Perhaps, another reason why Xcode sometimes drops to only two stars (**) in Apple store.)  I workaround this diffenciency by "spraying" prints throughout my Swift.  Pretty fast way to debug, though.